# What are the natural transformations induced by a category with finite products?

Tags: category-theory, functors, natural-transformations

**Source**: *Categories for the Working Mathematician*, second edition by Saunders Mac Lane.

**Proposition**: If a category $C$ has a terminal object $t$ and a product diagram $a\leftarrow a\times b\rightarrow b$ for any two of its objects, then $C$ has all finite products. The product objects provide, by $\langle a, b\rangle\mapsto a\times b$, a bifunctor $C\times C\to C$. **For any three objects $\mathbf{a, b}$ and $\mathbf{c}$ there is an isomorphism $\mathbf{\alpha=\alpha_{a, b, c}: a\times(b\times c)\cong(a\times b)\times c}$ natural in $\mathbf{a, b}$ and $\mathbf{c}$.**

**My Question**: I struggle with the boldface part. Take $c$, for example. I suppose for each fixed pair $\langle a, b\rangle$ the natural transformation, called it $\tau$, is between the two functors $S=a\times(b\times-)$ and $T=(a\times b)\times-: C\to C$. The object functions for $S$ and $T$ are obvious: $c\mapsto a\times(b\times c)$ and $c\mapsto(a\times b)\times c$. But what about the arrow functions? And when it comes to $\tau$, each $c$ of $C$ is mapped to which arrow of $C$?

The book can be a bit tough to follow sometimes; but I guess that's part of the charm. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you already familiar with the Yoneda Lemma? if so, I can provide a much easier answer that does not involve any diagrams or computations for that matter.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I am! Please do-I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: I think my answer in your recent question (concerning the naturality proof) is enough? ^^ There I also explain now $\tau$ is constructed with equations, and how you can work with it as well. The same approach works for the construction of the inverse.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg It sure is-I truly appreciate all your help. There are still a few details I want to hammer out completely because I have OCD, but your answer provides clear guidance on how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s a diagram of the relevant morphisms (produced with [quiver](https://q.uiver.app/)). The solid black arrows are the projections given by the definition of the product. The dotted red arrows are compositions of those projections. The dashed blue arrows are obtained by applying the universal properties of their target products to suitable black and red arrows.

[image: commutative diagram]

Composing the vertical blue arrows in the centre yields morphisms from the triple products to themselves. By chasing arrows, you can check that the composition of these morphisms with the projections of the triple products again yields those projections. By uniqueness of the universal property, it follows that these morphisms are the identity morphisms on the triple products, and thus the vertical blue arrows are isomorphisms between the triple products.

Here’s a diagram for how to obtain an arrow from $(a\times b)\times c$ to $(a\times b)\times c'$ given an arrow from $c$ to $c'$. The squiggly green line is the given arrow from $c$ to $c'$. As above, the black arrows are the projections of the products, the dotted red arrow is a composition, and the dashed blue arrow is obtained by applying the universal property.

[image: commutative diagram]

And here’s the diagram for obtaining an arrow from $a\times(b\times c)$ to $a\times(b\times c')$ given an arrow from $c$ to $c'$ (same colour/texture coding as before). The coloured arrows are obtained from right to left, each using the previous one.

[image: commutative diagram]

Comment: Regarding the blue arrows from $(a\times b)\times c$ to $a\times(b\times c)$: by taking FShrike's hint (also great answer btw), we get the two arrows $(a\times b)\times c\to a$ and $(a\times b)\times c\to b\times c$ in the first graph. But then by the universal property I would be getting an arrow $((a\times b)\times c)\times((a\times b)\times c)\to a\times(b\times c)$. So is it true then we just view $d\times d\sim d$ for all $d$ of $C$, by the uniqueness (up to isomorphism) of the product objects?

Comment: @DickGrayson: How do you get an arrow $((a\times b)\times c)\times((a\times b)\times c)\to a\times(b\times c)$? No, $d\times d\sim d$ usually doesn't hold. I agree, FShrike's answer is good – on an abstract level I actually find it more insightful than mine, but I thought these diagrams would also help you sort things out.

Comment: I had to accept yours because of the graphs. Well, I believe the universal property is this: given any two arrows $f_1: a_1\to b_1$ and $f_2: a_2\to b_2$, there exists a unique arrow $f_1\times f_2: a_1\times a_2\to b_1\times b_2$ such that $p_i(f_1\times f_2)=f_i=p_i$ holds, where $p_i: a_1\times a_2\to a_i$ is the projection. So maybe my understanding of the universal property is also off?

Comment: @DickGrayson: Yes, that's not the universal property (at least not the one I was referring to :-). The universal property of a product $a_1\times a_2$ with projections $p_i$ to the $a_i$ is that given an object $b$ and morphisms $f_i:b\to a_i$, there is a unique morphism $f:b\to a_1\times a_2$ such that $p_i\circ f=f_i$. It's a good exercise to go through the diagrams and see whether you understand how each of the dashed blue arrows is obtained by applying this.

Answer (score 2):

Some hints.

Let $T:C\times C\to C$ denote product. You then define $a\times(b\times c)$ on arrows and objects very easily as the composite functor $T\circ(1\times T):C\times C\times C\to C\times C\to C$. Similarly, $(a\times b)\times c$ stands for $T\circ(T\times 1)$. Well, that assumes you understand how $T$ is a functor. If the reader is not familiar with this, here's how it works:

> For an arrow $(f,g):(x,y)\to(x',y')$ in $C\times C$, $T(f,g)$ - usually written $f\times g$ - is some arrow $x\times y\to x'\times y'$; it is the unique arrow such that $\pi_1 T(f,g)=f\pi_1:x\times y\to x\to x'$ and $\pi_2T(f,g)=g\pi_2:x\times y\to y\to y'$. Such an arrow exists and is unambiguously defined precisely by the universal property of $x'\times y'$.
>
> This definition is an instance of the more general property that $\varprojlim$ is a functor, and $(f,g)$ defines a natural transformation between the diagrams whose limits are $x\times y$ and $x'\times y'$.

To get a map $(a\times b)\times c\to a\times(b\times c)$, use the product universal property in a similar fashion. You just need to find arrows $(a\times b)\times c\to a$ and $(a\times b)\times c\to b\times c$. The only sensible ones you can think of (if you're stuck, what are they for $C=\mathsf{Set}$?) are the correct ones.

Comment: Maybe the OP (and other readers) also need to know how $T$ is defined on morphisms.

Comment: @Fshrike I appreciate the hint. I now believe I have confusion about the definition of the universal property of the product diagram. Given $f_1: a_1\to b_1$ and $f_2: a_2\to b_2$, is it true that $T(\langle f_1, f_2\rangle)=f_1\times f_2$, where $f_1\times f_2: a_1\times a_2\to b_1\times b_2$ is the unique arrow such that $p_i(f_1\times f_2)=f_ip_i$?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Ah I assumed functoriality of products was known. I'll update

Comment: @DickGrayson Your comment is correct