# Why are the isomorphisms induced by the category with finite products natural?

Tags: category-theory, functors, natural-transformations

A follow-up question to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4840627/506332).

**Source**: *Categories for the Working Mathematician*, second edition by Saunders Mac Lane.

**Proposition**: If a category $C$ has a terminal object $t$ and a product diagram $a\leftarrow a\times b\rightarrow b$ for any two of its objects, then $C$ has all finite products. The product objects provide, by $\langle a, b\rangle\mapsto a\times b$, a bifunctor $C\times C\to C$. **For any three objects $\mathbf{a, b}$ and $\mathbf{c}$ there is an isomorphism $\mathbf{\alpha=\alpha_{a, b, c}: a\times(b\times c)\overset{\tau}{\cong}(a\times b)\times c}$ natural in $\mathbf{a, b}$ and $\mathbf{c}$.**

**My Question**: I struggle to show the naturality of $\tau$. Take $c$, for example. Obviously we want to show the following diagram is commutative:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
(a\times b)\times c @>\tau c>> a\times(b\times c)\\
@V Sf V V @VV Tf V\\
(a\times b)\times c' @>>\tau c'> a\times(b\times c').
\end{CD}

Here $S$ and $T$ are the two functors defined by $(a\times b)\times-: C\to C$ and $a\times(b\times-): C\to C$, respectively; $f: c\to c'$ is an arrow of $C$. Now, I managed to show that $Tf\circ\tau c$ is the unique arrow $\gamma$ such that $p_1\gamma=g\circ h$ (here $h: (a\times b)\times c\to a\times b$ and $g: (a\times b)\to a$ are the obvious projections) AND $p_2\gamma=s\circ t$, ($t: (a\times b)\times c\to b\times c$ and $s: b\times c\to b\times c'$ are the blue arrows found in the first and third graph respectively [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4840627/506332)), where $p_i$ are projections. I ought to do the same thing again and show $\tau c'\circ Sf$ is also $\gamma$; but that proves to be problematic.

What am I missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to use the definitions? Remember what a morphism into a product *is*. It is determined by ....

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's show naturality in all three arguments. We can just verify this using the definitions. I will use equations instead of commutative diagrams (both approaches are valid, and I present this one here since it is lesser known but has some advantages as well).

Let me denote the projection onto the $i$th factor by $p_i$, regardless of which product is used (this will always be clear from the context).

Then $\tau : (a \times b) \times c \to a \times (b \times c)$ is defined by the three equations
$$\begin{align*}
p_1 \tau &= p_1 p_1 \\
p_1 p_2 \tau &= p_2 p_1 \\
p_2 p_2 \tau &= p_2\end{align*}$$
This is a bit short notation, but it is unambiguous nonetheless. For example, $p_1 p_2 \tau = p_2 p_1$ means that

$$(a \times b) \times c \xrightarrow{\tau} a \times (b \times c) \xrightarrow{p_2} b \times c \xrightarrow{p_1} b$$

is equal to

$$(a \times b) \times c \xrightarrow{p_1} a \times b \xrightarrow{p_2} b.$$

The three equations define $\tau$ completely by the universal property (=definition) of products in a category (the first one defines $p_1 \tau$, the second and third one define $p_2 \tau$, hence we have $\tau$).

An even much more concise definition of $\tau$ uses [generalized elements](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/generalized+element), because then the equations above simply translate to the usual formula $\tau((x,y),z)=(x,(y,z))$, which also makes everything here (also the construction of $\tau$ itself) trivial, but for the sake of learning let's ignore this path for now, and I just wanted to mention it.

If $f : a \to a'$, $g : b \to b'$, $h : c \to c'$ are morphisms, then
$$(f \times g) \times h : (a \times b) \times c \to (a' \times b') \times c'$$
is defined by the three equations
$$\begin{align*}
p_1 p_1 ((f \times g) \times h)  & = f p_1 p_1\\
p_2 p_1 ((f \times g) \times h)  & = g p_2 p_1\\
p_2 ((f \times g) \times h)  & = h p_2
\end{align*}$$

The definition of $f \times (g \times h)$ is completely analogous and also consists of three equations, which I omit here. The isomorphism $\tau'$ is defined in the same way as $\tau$, just with $a',b',c'$ instead of $a,b,c$.

The claimed naturality is just the equation

$$(f \times (g \times h)) \circ \tau = \tau' \circ ((f \times g) \times h)$$
of morphisms $(a \times b) \times c \to a' \times (b' \times c')$.

As before it suffices to post-compose the morphisms with $p_1$ and $p_1 p_2$ and $p_2 p_2$ to prove their equality (again, by the universal property, i.e. definition of products).

So we have to verify three equations. And guess what, they of course follow from our definitions / equations before! It is just a matter of writing it down. The computation is so straight forward that it could even be done (and formalized) by computer algebra software these days.

Let us denote the definitions of $\tau$ (likewise $\tau'$),  $(f \times g) \times h$, $f \times (g \times h)$, by $\mathrm{D1}, \mathrm{D2}, \mathrm{D3}$.

**First equation** ($p_1$):

$$\begin{align*}
p_1 \, (f \times (g \times h)) \, \tau & \stackrel{\mathrm{D3}}{=} f p_1 \tau \\
& \stackrel{\mathrm{D1}}{=} f p_1 p_1 \\
& \stackrel{\mathrm{D2}}{=} p_1 p_1 ((f \times g) \times h) \\
& \stackrel{\mathrm{D1'}}{=} p_1 \tau' ((f \times g) \times h) \end{align*}$$

**Second equation** ($p_1 p_2$):

$$\begin{align*}
p_1 p_2 (f \times (g \times h)) \, \tau & \stackrel{\mathrm{D3}}{=} g p_1 p_2 \tau \\
& \stackrel{\mathrm{D1}}{=} g p_2 p_1 \\
& \stackrel{\mathrm{D2}}{=} p_2 p_1 ((f \times g) \times h) \\
& \stackrel{\mathrm{D1'}}{=} p_1 p_2 \tau' ((f \times g) \times h)
\end{align*}$$

**Third equation** ($p_2 p_2$):

$$\begin{align*}
p_2 p_2 (f \times (g \times h)) \, \tau & \stackrel{\mathrm{D3}}{=} h p_2 p_2 \tau \\
& \stackrel{\mathrm{D1}}{=} h p_2 \\
& \stackrel{\mathrm{D2}}{=} p_2 ((f \times g) \times h) \\
& \stackrel{\mathrm{D1'}}{=} p_2 p_2 \tau' ((f \times g) \times h)
\end{align*}$$

Comment: You beat me to it...